# VBA function adding the values of two cells

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am totally new to VBA and was asked to create a function that adds the numerical values of two cells.

I came up with the following, but I am given the message

> Compile Error: Cannot assign to array, with `Additionex`

at the bottom marked as the problem…

Could anybody help out?

```
Function Additionex(num1 As Double, num2 As Double) As Double()
    Dim num3 As Double

    num3 = num1 + num2

    Additionex = num3
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

`Double()` is an array of Double-type variables. You want `as Double`.

```
Function Additionex(num1 As Double, num2 As Double) As Double

    Dim num3 As Double

    num3 = num1 + num2

    Additionex = num3

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Evaluate

```
Public Function Additionex(ByVal num1 As Double, ByVal num2 As Double) As Double
    Additionex = Evaluate(num1 + num2)
End Function
```

If you want something more generic that takes ranges (your two cells as arguments) and can handle errors consider something like:

```
Public Function Additionex(ByVal cell1 As Range, ByVal cell2 As Range) As Variant
    If IsNumeric(cell1.Value) And IsNumeric(cell2.Value) Then
        Additionex = Evaluate(num1 + num2)
    Else
       Additionex = CVErr(xlna)
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Could you shortly explain on this case the preference of ByVal.

Comment: What do I gain?

Comment: you are passing the actual value of an argument not a reference. The advantage of passing an argument ByVal is that it protects a variable from being changed by the procedure.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/passing-arguments-by-value-and-by-reference Same principles apply to VBA.

Comment: Could I say that a rule of thumb is ByRef for objects, ByVal for the rest? I meant do I gain something in speed of execution or whatever, or is it just correctness. I mean as I understand this, the default is ByRef and this case works anyhow. Thx, I'll check that out, sorry for bothering.

Comment: No you can't simply say that. I will get in trouble if I say the wrong thing and a rubber duck crew sees it. Worth popping by to see [them](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) for a correct explanation of the intricacies. Basically, if I want to change a value with the passed to sub/function I use ByRef.

Comment: @VBasic2008 The same rule applies for objects, but `ByVal` and `ByRef` apply to the *object reference itself*. If you pass an object `ByVal`, the called procedure can't alter the object pointer (set it to a new object or set it to `Nothing`).  It can still alter properties of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it an array:

```
Function Additionex(num1 As Double, num2 As Double) As Double
    Dim num3 As Double
    num3 = num1 + num2
    Additionex = num3
End Function
```

[image]